# 3D graphic clean image in loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, mplot3d

I have this graph inside a loop, the problem is that it opens a new image for each iteration, my **plt.clf()** does not seem to be working, how can I fix this problem?

```
plt.ion()

for k in range(1,10):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):

        for j in range(0,len(x[i])-1):

       plt.clf()
       fig = plt.figure()
       ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
       ax.set_title('Iteration %s\n' % (str(k)))
       ax.set_xlabel('X')
       ax.set_ylabel('Y')
       ax.set_zlabel('Z')
       ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
       ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
       ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)

      plt.show()
      plt.pause(0.05)
```

I hid the code because I believe the problem occurs in the piece of code I posted here

P.S.: I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is setting `fig = plt.figure()` each iteration and then cleaning up the plot using `plt.gcf().clear()`, you should rather do something like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

x = [[1,5],[2,4]]
fig = plt.figure()

for k in range(1,10):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):

        for j in range(0,len(x[i])-1):    

            ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
            ax.set_title('Iteration %s\n' % (str(k)))
            ax.set_xlabel('X')
            ax.set_ylabel('Y')
            ax.set_zlabel('Z')
            ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
            ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
            ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)
            plt.show()
            plt.pause(0.5)
            plt.gcf().clear()
```

Comment: you mind showing more of your code then? Specifically the loop of `plt.show()`

Comment: I edited the code as requested, look at the question again

Comment: @QuestionsOverflow I edited my answer, it indeed wasn't working as I thought it would.